# Unable to load pandas in R reticulate due to missing GLIBCXX_3.4.29

Tags: python, r, pandas, glibc, reticulate

I'm trying to use `R`'s `reticulate` package for loading `python`'s `pandas` package in `R`.

I have `python3.8`, and I installed `pandas` through `conda`. In `python` `pandas` imports fine but in `R`, after loading `reticulate` I get this error:

```
> pd <- import("pandas")
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) :
  ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /home/mnd/miniconda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

I read through [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65349875/where-can-i-find-glibcxx-3-4-29) but my `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6` does not have `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` in it (it has `GLIBCXX_3.4` to `GLIBCXX_3.4.28`), and `GLIBCXX_3.4.29` cannot be found in [this ftp](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/).

I also tried following this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67873498/error-while-importing-pandas-in-r-via-reticulate) by installing `pandas` from `R` with `reticulate`: `reticulate::py_install("pandas", force = TRUE)`, which completed, but the `pd <- import("pandas")` command results with the same error above.

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue on Amazon Linux 2. One solution that worked for me was to adjust the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable prior to installing `reticulate`. Specifically on my machine:

```bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/anaconda3/lib
```

While this works in a pinch, I am dubious that it's an ideal solution for a production environment. In my experience if you find yourself having to adjust `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` then it suggests that something (e.g. linker options) may not be properly configured in the environment. For more on this, see for example: https://www.hpc.dtu.dk/?page_id=1180

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling pandas within the conda virtual environment

```
pip install pandas --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall
```